# Як правильно: Міс чи міз?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Читала "Черепахи аж до низу" Джона Гріна в перекладі Марії Пухлій, і там було "міз". Раніше завжди зустрічала "міс". І в мережі нічого про "міз" не знайшла. Як буде правильно: "міс" чи "міз"?

Comment: Можете навести цитату з використанням "міз" щоб порівняти з англійським текстом?

Answer (score 4):

Це різні слова:

- Mrs (читається [місіз]; укр. зазв. трансл. як місіс) — звернення до одруженої жінки.
- Miss (читається [міс]; укр. зазв. трансл. як міс) — звернення до неодруженої жінки.
- Ms (читається [міз]) — універсальне звернення до жінки (незалежно від її сімейного стану — може бути одруженою чи ні).

Оскільки Ms [міз] увішло в широкий вжиток у англійській мові порівняно нещодавно, українські словники можуть його ще не фіксувати (спочатку цим словом мають «насититися» перекладні книжки, щоб українські словники мали підставу його зафіксувати).

<sub>Вище наведені сучасні значення цих слів, раніше акценти бути частково іншими. З малою ймовірністю воно може виявитися й нестандартною транслітерацією слова Miss [міс].</sub>

Comment: Ця книжка вийшла англійською у [2017 році](http://www.johngreenbooks.com/turtles-all-the-way-down-book/), і Google Books знаходить у тексті [5 скороченнь "Ms."](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=440oDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Turtles+All+the+Way+Down&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiClti_sp7dAhWuiqYKHcuVAoAQ6AEIMDAB#v=onepage&q=ms.&f=false).

Comment: Приклади відповідних абзаців: > Яка роль була в цій постановці у мене? Товариша Головного Героя. Я була Подругою Дейзі або Донькою Міз Голмс. Я кимось комусь доводилася. 

> What was my part in this play? The Sidekick. I was Daisy's Friend, or Ms. Holmes's Daughter. I was somebody's something.

Answer (score 2):

З СУМ -20

> ***[Міс](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=51631&page=1644)*** -  невідм., ж. 1. Ввічлива назва дівчини в англомовних країнах, що вживається звичайно перед прізвищем або ім'ям.

Словник іншомовник слів

> ***[Міс](http://slovopedia.org.ua/36/53404/244007.html)*** - (англ.) **1.** Ввічлива назва дівчини в англійців та американців. **2.** *розм.*, заст.Вихователька, гувернантка.

Словник англіцизмів

> ***[Міс](http://slovopedia.org.ua/46/53404/301661.html)*** «панна», форма звертання до дівчини в англомовних країнах (вживається перед прізвищем або ім'ям) - Miss < англ. mistress
>   «господиня».
>
> ***[Міз](http://slovopedia.org.ua/46/53404/302194.html)*** л.н.а. «звертання до жінки, сімейний стан якої невідомий» - Ms. < контамінація англ. Miss «міс» і англ. Mrs. «місіс».

Слово "МІЗ" знайшла лише в одному словнику. Більш вживане слово "МІС".

Answer (score 0):

Знайшов відповідь на [англійському блозі](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/ms-mrs-miss-difference/), а тому перекладу, щоб було зрозуміліше:

Слово "**міс**" ми вживаємо, коли звертаємося до неодруженої жінки, після чого потрібно назвати її прізвище, наприклад - міс Джонсон. Однак в деяких регіонах після "міс" називають ім'я дівчини.

Слово "**місіс**" ми вживаємо, коли звертаємося до одруженої жінки або вдови, після чого зазвичай називаємо прізвище її чоловіка або й навіть його ім'я (якщо ми не знаємо імені жінки) - місіс Дональд Бельмонд.

Слово "**міз**" ми вживаємо, коли ми не знаємо чи одружена жінка чи ні. Це такий еквівалент до слова "містер", яким називають як і одружених, так і неодружених чоловіків.

Однак, варто зазначити, що і "міс", і "міз" можна вживати, якщо нам невідомо чи одружена жінка.